# sshd on Lineage OS returns authentication error

Tags: ssh, android, authentication

I wanted to enable sshd on LineageOS by using this tutorial:

[https://lisas.de/~alex/?p=237](https://lisas.de/%7Ealex/?p=237)

it seems to work but I just get authentication errors:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa shell@192.168.1.161
shell@192.168.1.161: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I double checked, but the pubkey is correctly in `/data/ssh/authorized_keys`, permissions should be fine as well, but when I start the sshd manually with `/system/bin/sshd -f /data/ssh/sshd_config -D -d` I see the following errors:

```
debug1: trying public key file /data/ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/data/ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for shell from 192.168.1.161 port 59772 ssh2: RSA SHA256:0JRfIey1s3254h32ads218wrXGHexk
```

but thats how it looks:

```
walleye:/data/ssh # ls -la | grep author                                                                 
-rw-------  1 shell  root   1480 2020-12-30 22:52 authorized_keys
```

is this wrong somehow? Maybe because Iam running this as root on the server but its only readable by shell?

Comment: Instead of presenting the client log you should check the sshd server log. It may contain more information what is going wrong. To do so I would recommend not to start sshd via init script but start it manually via adb so that you can provide additional parameters and see the console output.

Comment: thats what I was asking in my last sentence :) But how exactly do I start it manually and not via init script? Or where could I find log files for sshd?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: `authorized_keys` should have `644` permissions _(e.g. unless you're logging in as `shell`, `authorized_keys` can't be read; user `root`  should have access, which it does not, nor does group `root`)_

Comment: @JW0914 I still get the same error even with `644` on `authorized_keys`, is it possibly because `/data` is `drwxrwx--x  61 system system  4096 2021-01-13 10:49 data` ?